# How does the raster package handle no data/flagged values of ncdf4 files when loading them into raster objects?

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

I have ncdf4 files of [NDVI](https://land.copernicus.eu/global/products/ndvi) measurs. When I load them with `raster("path/to/file.nc")` it seems that no data ("missing values") is replaced by one value that is within the ndvi value range (e.g. 0.928). Here is na [ncdf4-example](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4e3iflsvkpt26jq/AADh2eJ1DLQGrWqCHMKj-m-Za?dl=0).

Here is what I've done for all my ncdf-files:

```
file<- list.files(path= paste0(wd, "/in/"), pattern = 'nc$', full.names=TRUE, recursive=T)
dem<- raster("dem.tif")

for (i in 1:length(file)){
      r<- raster(file[i])
      r.crop<- crop(r,dem_c, filename = paste0(wd,"/out/", as.character(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", basename(file[i])))),".tif"), overwrite = T)
}
```

What I want to do ist to crop all `.nc` files using `dem.tif` first and then calculate mean values over the time period (all croped files using `calc()`). Loading and croping works fine, also calculating the mean. However when no data is repalced by a value within the ndvi range this makes no sense at all.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Here is the print out for the first nc file using `ncdf4::nc_open`

```
File E:/path/c_gls_NDVI_199804010000_GLOBE_VGT_V2.2.1.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):

     3 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        char crs[]   (Contiguous storage)  
            long_name: coordinate reference system
            semi_major_axis: 6378137
            spatial_ref: GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
            grid_mapping_name: latitude_longitude
            _CoordinateTransformType: Projection
            _CoordinateAxisTypes: GeoX GeoY
            inverse_flattening: 298.257223563
            GeoTransform: -180.0000000000 0.0089285714 0.0 80.0000000000 0.0 -0.0089285714
            longitude_of_prime_meridian: 0
        unsigned byte NDVI[lon,lat,time]   (Chunking: [3102,1207,1])  (Compression: shuffle,level 4)
            _FillValue: 255
            grid_mapping: crs
            scale_factor: 0.00400000018998981
            missing_value: 255
            flag_meanings: Missing cloud snow sea background
            add_offset: -0.0799999982118607
            long_name: Normalized Difference Vegetation Index 1KM
            standard_name: normalized_difference_vegetation_index
            flag_values: 251
             flag_values: 252
             flag_values: 253
             flag_values: 254
             flag_values: 255
            units: 
            valid_range: 0
             valid_range: 250
        unsigned short TIME_GRID[lon,lat,time]   (Chunking: [2240,872,1])  (Compression: shuffle,level 4)
            _FillValue: 65535
            grid_mapping: crs
            valid_range: 0
             valid_range: 18720
            long_name: Time Grid
            units: minutes since 1998-04-01 07:36:59
            calendar: standard
            missing_value: 65535

     3 dimensions:
        lon  Size:40320
            standard_name: longitude
            long_name: longitude
            DIMENSION_LABELS: lon
            units: degrees_east
            _CoordinateAxisType: Lon
            axis: X
        lat  Size:15680
            standard_name: latitude
            long_name: latitude
            DIMENSION_LABELS: lat
            units: degrees_north
            _CoordinateAxisType: Lat
            axis: Y
        time  Size:1   *** is unlimited ***
            units: days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
            long_name: Time
            calendar: standard
            axis: T

    19 global attributes:
        Conventions: CF-1.6
        parent_identifier: urn:cgls:global:ndvi_v2_1km
        copyright: Copernicus Service information 2017
        time_coverage_end: 1998-04-10T23:59:59Z
        title: 10-daily Normalized Difference Vegetation Index 1KM: GLOBE 1998-04-01T00:00:00Z
        product_version: V2.2.1
        long_name: Normalized Difference Vegetation Index
        time_coverage_start: 1998-04-01T00:00:00Z
        platform: SPOT-4
        processing_mode: Reprocessing
        orbit_type: LEO
        references: http://land.copernicus.eu/global/products/ndvi
        source: Derived from EO satellite imagery
        history: 2017-03-11 Processing line NDVI 1km using SPOT-VGT Collection 3 input
        archive_facility: VITO
        identifier: urn:cgls:global:ndvi_v2_1km:NDVI_199804010000_GLOBE_VGT_V2.2.1
        sensor: VEGETATION-1
        institution: VITO NV
        processing_level: L3
```

Comment: If the cdf file has a flagged nodata value then it will be NA in raster class objects. If this is not the case then the nodata value is not identified in the cdf file. It should not be within the range of the rasters values and it the nodata value is I would contact whomever produced the data to rectify it. What does the metadata say?

Comment: Indeed, there are flags ranging from 250 to 254 (nodata, clouds, water, snow). But they do not appear within the whole value range. BTW when I open the nc files in QGIS, everything is fine...

Comment: You could just deal with NA values in R via something like: r[r == 250] <- NA

Comment: Can you provide a smaller example to test on? Just crop the one you uploaded to a smaller area containing both values and NA. By the way ncView also fails at representing the sea values as NA and sets them to `0.936`, which is close to `255*0.004-0.08`, that is: `NA*scale+offset`.

Comment: By the way if you remove the `valid_range` attribute (e.g. with `ncatted`) `raster` will then, for some reason, understand the NA correctly... except when plotting. Very weird. I did some tests (on the original file!) cropping to 0:20,0:20. It seems that R is partially aware of these NA: the most common value is `~0.936`, however it is NOT displayed if you do `rle(r1[])$values[1]`. However if you plot and use `nas <- click()`, you will find the culprit value and can do something along the lines of `r1 <- r1[r1 != nas[1,]]` to remove the NA.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, then it has to do with the scaling factor and the offset? But then I don't understand how other values look correct? It looks like that clouds (or generally flagged/missing data pixel) have values near 0.9...

Comment: @ Jeffrey Evans: Thank you I also thought about this, but there are no values higher than 1.

Comment: After this correspondence I read again the user manual of the copernicus ndvi products and can now understand better what is meant with offset and scale factor! The post from AF7 led me to this, thank you... The ndvi values of this product are restricted to [-0.08:0.92]. Values above are now dedicted for flags (digital numbers between 251 and 255). Now I can easily calculate "physical values" for the flags and remove them.